# Unity: with a 3D perspective camera, how can I keep 2 objects at the same distance from the screen edge?

Tags: unity-game-engine

In my game, there are 2 tanks. I define camPoint as the center of the tanks in world coordinates - and this is the point the camera points to.

Problem is that this doesn't take into account the camera perspective. In the image, camPoint is at the yellow spot, but you can see that the tanks are not at the same distance from the edges:

[Yellow dot is current camPoint, pink dot is desired camPoint](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iyoLy.png)

The desired location for camPoint is at the pink dot, so that both tanks are at the same distance from the edge. But how do I find that exact spot? I'm sure it can be calculated, but I haven't been able to figure it out.

Comment: Is camera static or should it move depending on tanks movement? Should camera zoom in and out?

Comment: The camera moves along with the tanks. Camera can zoom in and out, and sometimes rotate as well. FoV doesn't change (camera zoom is done by moving camera away).

Comment: I have tried using WorldToViewportPoint for each tank, then finding the (0.5,0.5) point (center of viewport) and translating that to World coordinates, but the camera kept jumping for some reason.

Comment: Go watch the Tanks video tutorial on the unity site. It goes over this exact process, using two tanks too!

Comment: Will check it out, thanks!

Comment: Nice video. But they're using an orthographic projection, in which case the calculations are easy enough. I haven't found an answer for a perspective projection.

Comment: I'm not sure if it would work but try to calculate middle point not in the world space but in screenspace and than use screentoworldpoint to find middle point for camera. Also use LateUpdate() for camera movement to avoid jaggy movement

Comment: Is the desired camera position dependant on the current camera position (leading to iterative adjustments), or is it calculated entirely from the tank positions, a defined cam distance, and a defined view direction (leading to immediate, sometimes radical change)? What about the cam's up-vector, is it supposed to be facing up always, or can it freely rotate?

Comment: The solution I posted works, but I'd rather not use it since I can't undestand how it behaves. Instead of making an immediate change, it does so in steps, while it shouldn't. It's like Unity calculates viewport coordinates from outside the view wrongly. Up is always the same btw.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [Camera.ScreenToWorldPoint](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Camera.ScreenToWorldPoint.html)
and [Camera.WorldToScreenPoint](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Camera.WorldToScreenPoint.html)

For example, if all you want is for the 2 tanks to always have the same distance from the edges of the screen, you can transform the world position to screen position, compute the camera orientation in screen space and then transform it back into world space taking the camera distance and perspective into account.

Comment: I have tried using WorldToViewportPoint for each tank, then finding the (0.5,0.5) point (center of viewport) and translating that to World coordinates, but the camera kept jumping for some reason.

Comment: Well WorldToViewportPoint is different than WorldToScreenPoint, like one is screen space (2d) and the other is viewport space (3d).

Comment: From what I read, Viewport is just Screen normalized (instead of pixelwidth,pixelheight it's 1,1).

Comment: what do you mean by "jumping" are you moving your camera in LateUpdate()?

Answer (score 0):

I found a working solution:

1) Store each tank's position on the viewport in arrays/lists.

2) Find the centerpoint by using the min/max as in the code below.

3) Convert that centerpoint back to world coordinates by using the x,y centerpoint found and for z, the typical distance to the camera.

```
    for (var i = 0; i < numberOfTanks; i++) {
        tanksX[i] = camcam.WorldToViewportPoint(tanks[i].transform.position).x;
        tanksY[i] = camcam.WorldToViewportPoint(tanks[i].transform.position).y;
    }

    tanksXmin = Mathf.Min (tanksX);
    tanksYmin = Mathf.Min (tanksY);
    tanksXmax = Mathf.Max (tanksX);
    tanksYmax = Mathf.Max (tanksY);
    camScript.camPoint = camcam.ViewportToWorldPoint(new Vector3((tanksXmax + tanksXmin) / 2, (tanksYmax + tanksYmin) / 2, camScript.camDist));
    camScript.camPoint = new Vector3 (camScript.camPoint.x, tankOffsetY+camScript.zoomLevel, camScript.camPoint.z);
```

And then in cam's LateUpdate():

```
    offset = new Vector3 (offsetXZ, offsetY, offsetXZ);
    transform.position = camPoint+offset;
    transform.LookAt (camPoint, Vector3.up);
```

Notice that I'm using the Y axis as the axis Unity typically defines as 'Z'.

There is some jumping going on when zooming in and out, but that's not a problem for today.

Thank you for your answers everyone!

Comment: The strange thing is that it takes a few steps for this to actually get to the point, which is what I'm trying to fix sill.